# Cyclically mapping flat arrays of different sizes and summing the values

Tags: php, arrays, sum, mapping, cyclic

I have an issue with two arrays that I need to combine, where the first array contains a list of campaign names ( page_data ) like

```
[
    "Campaign 1",
    "Campaign 2",
    "Campaign 3"
]
```

and another array that contains number of leads for the campaigns. But this array will contain twice as many keys as the campaign array like this:

```
[
    222,
    342,
    71,
    33,
    43,
    665
]
```

It contains twice as many keys, because it will take leads from two different forms, so the values for `key 0` and `key 3` will be for campaign 1 and `key 2` and `key 4` will be for campaign 2. It will always be this way. If there are 5 campaigns, leads array will have 10 keys and `key 0` and `key 5` will be for campaign one, `key 1` an `key 6` for campaign 2, etc.

And then I have this piece of code to combine ( push ):

```
foreach (json_decode($result) as $key) {                                           
   foreach ($pages["page_data"] as $p => $pvalue) {
       array_push(
           $leadArray,
           array(
               "pageName" => $pvalue["form_name"],
               "pageLeads" => $key[$p]
           )
       );              
    }        
}
```

That will incorrectly make an array that looks something like:

```
[
    "campaign 1" => 222, 
    "campaign 2" => 342, 
    "campaign 3" => 71
]
```

But that will only take keys 0,1,2 and so key 3,4,5 will not be in the array.

What I want is key 0 and key 3, key 1 and key 4, etc. in the leads array to be combined so the the new leads array will be

```
[
    255,
    386,
    736
]
```

which I can then combine with the campaigns array as the number of keys from the two arrays will now match which will give me an array that looks like

```
[
    "campaign 1" => 255, 
    "campaign 2" => 386, 
    "campaign 3" => 736
]
```

Comment: I would suggest using `for()` instead of `foreach()` with such complex arrays to keep things simple and easy to handle.

Comment: What are your expecting output? Your question is not clear at some place.

Comment: In addition to @RedBottle 's comment, seems like you need modulo operator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-chunk.php) function for split your second array and it will be easy to sum values.

When you use this function, your array will splitted into two arrays. In first array you will have values 0, 1, 2, and in second you will have 3, 4, 5 values. Now iterate through your first array, using keys you will have access to value pairs: 0-3, 1-4, 2-5.

Check out this code:

```
<?php

$array1 = [0 => "Campaign 1", 1 => "Campaign 2", 2 => "Campaign 3"];
$array2 = [0 => 222, 1 => 342, 2 => 71, 3 => 33, 4 => 43, 5 => 665];

$chunkedArray2 = array_chunk($array2, count($array1), false);

$result = [];
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = $chunkedArray2[0][$key] + $chunkedArray2[1][$key];
}

var_dump($result);
```

And result is:

```
Array
(
    [Campaign 1] => 255
    [Campaign 2] => 385
    [Campaign 3] => 736
)
```

Comment: This answer is hardcoded to process/sum exactly two elements from the second array for every element in the first array.  If code is needed by researchers to handle more variable volumes of data, then this answer is not suitable. https://3v4l.org/Y7k7b

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid chunking and transposing by leveraging the modulus value between the current index and the count of the groups array.

This is optimized for efficiency (because it makes no iterated function calls), has the lowest time complexity (because it only iterates the values array once), and will work when you have [any number of values](https://3v4l.org/ftH0i) to process.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jElCV))

```
$groups = ["Campaign 1", "Campaign 2", "Campaign 3"];
$values = [222, 342, 71, 33, 43, 665];

$count = count($groups);
$result = [];
foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    $group = $groups[$index % $count]; 
    $result[$group] = ($result[$group] ?? 0) + $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Campaign 1' => 255,
  'Campaign 2' => 385,
  'Campaign 3' => 736,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$result = json_decode($result);
$count = count($result);
$final = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value){
  $final[$value] = $pages["page_data"][$key] + $pages["page_data"][$key+$count];
}
var_dump($final);
```

Comment: Please [edit] this answer to include an explanation of how it works.  It would be great if you could prove that your answer works by including an online sandbox demo link.

Answer (score 0):

@aslawin approach may be realized a litle easy with some functions

```
$array1 = [0 => "Campaign 1", 1 => "Campaign 2", 2 => "Campaign 3"];
$array2 = [0 => 222, 1 => 342, 2 => 71, 3 => 33, 4 => 43, 5 => 665];

$res = array_combine($array1, 
           array_map(function($i1, $i2) { return $i1+$i2; },
                 ...array_chunk($array2, count($array1))))
```

---

reply to comment: it's not obvious that the OP needs more than twice the length of the second array, but the code can easily be rewritten for any length

```
$array1 = [0 => "Campaign 1", 1 => "Campaign 2", 2 => "Campaign 3"];
$array2 = [222, 342, 71, 33, 43, 665, -255, -385, -736];

$res = array_combine($array1, 
           array_map(function(...$ar) { return array_sum($ar); },
                 ...array_chunk($array2, count($array1))));
                 
print_r($res);
```

output

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: @mickmackusa i've added a new edition of the code :)